# Convert collection of array to object

Tags: php

I'm currently pushing array data. How can I return the object like this:

```
"data": [
    {
        "apartment": {
            {
                "id": xxx,
                "show": "xxx,
            },
            {
                "id": xxx,
                "show": "xxx",
            },
```

and not like this:

```
 "data": [
    {
        "apartment": {
            "0": {
                "id": xxx,
                "show": "xxx,
            },
            "1" : {
                "id": xxx,
                "show": "xxx",
            },
```

Comment: What would be the difference if they are in same sequence?

Comment: yes i tried to cast it to (object) but the index is still showing

Comment: like for example this https://github.com/ellipsesynergie/api-response it returns the data without the index.

Comment: I feel like there is a lot of context missing in your question. What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: I'm trying to remove the index "0" from the list. So the data would look like this {
                "id": xxx,
                "show": "xxx,
            },
            {
                "id": xxx,
                "show": "xxx",
            }

Comment: Are you trying to get valid JSON to represent your first structure?

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
data[] = array("id" => 1)
```

Will add a named array to the data array.

```
data = [ {"id" => 1} ]
```

If you want data to be a named array, you should add your `"id" => 1` like this:

```
data[1] = {"id" => 1}
```

This will result in:

```
data = { 1 => {"id" => 1} }
```

Comment: yes but how can i do it when i use data[] = array('id' => 1);